# C# Report Creation

Tags: c#, data-visualization, reporting, visual-studio

I'm looking for a report generator in C#. I want the user to be able to input a collection of variables: the cost of each item, percentage discount, and the total cost of job etc. etc.

When they click 'Generate' I want to take all of these variables and place them into a pre-structured report - with the logo of the company in the corner, an address and the name of the user structured into it as well (etc.).

I'm using VS2015 Professional so it needs to be compatible with that (and C#). I know that Crystal Reports has been suggested in the past but I can't seem to find anywhere that states it's now supported in VS2015?

I am the sole developer in this task so there shouldn't be a need to worry about > 5 license restrictions. Something I suppose along the lines of this;

[image: A Detailed Sales Report]

Answer (score 1):

[DevExpress](http://devexpress.com) XtraReports can do this.

It is

- .NET, so allows for use in C#
- integrates into Visual Studio
- comes with a report designer
- is available for WPF, WinForms or ASP.NET

As long as you bring the items into a hierarchical form (list of lists) and they have `public` properties, things will work nicely and easily.

A single technology (WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET) is at ~900 USD, all technologies are at ~1500 USD. The license is perpetual and per developer. You get updates for 1 year. Support is done mainly via forums, but reaction times and provided solutions are ok.

Downside: the price may not be acceptable if Reports is the only feature you use.

Screenshot of a similar report provided with by the WinForms Reports Demo:

[image: DevExpress WinForms Report Demo]

Answer (score 1):

[Syncfusion Essential Reports](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/report-viewer) can be used to display Reports in .NET applications : [Sample](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/reportviewer/defaultfunctionalities.aspx). The sample linked to is for ASP.NET, but the Report Viewer is available for WPF/ASP.NET/ASP.NET MVC, JavaScript, WinRT (UWP will be added soon).

Reports are serialized in [Report Definition Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Report_Definition_Language) and can be created from within Visual Studio (RDLC) or using the Report Designer provided by Syncfusion.

The report viewer can be embedded in your application and reports can be created by the end users using the [Report Designer](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/report-designer).If you are using Microsoft SQL Server, you can also use the [Report Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42301) to create reports.

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at [Stimulsoft Reports](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/downloads). They have C#-NET-Framework based reporting tools for WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC platforms.

It is quite ordinary task to create a report like yours. Similar report template can be found [here](http://web.stimulsoft.com/Designer.aspx?reportname=ParametersDetailedOrders).

Note: I work for Stimulsoft.

The type of License depends on how many developers of your company will work with our reporting tool in development of your application.
Our products are licensed per developer seats (The developer is a person who takes part in the development of your application and builds, compiles, links your application and our assemblies present in this process). A build server (a PC machine which runs automatically the project compilation) also requires a license. Three types of licensing are available:

- Single License. This type of license allows you to use our product for one developer. The developer is a person who has access to .dll files and uses them in development;
- Team License. This type of license allows you to use our product for up to 4 developers;
- Site License. This type of license allows you to use our product for an unlimited number of developers at a single physical address. Physical address means a location on the Earth's surface (the Postal address of your organization). For example, if the company is located in two or more buildings standing around, the separate Licenses are required correspondingly for developers in these buildings;
- WorldWide License. This type of license can be used by unlimited number of developers at an unlimited number of locations.

Buying a Stimulsoft product you get two things: a License and Subscription. The license gives you ability to use the software in your projects. The license is perpetual. The subscription gives you ability to get the software updates for a period of year since the date of purchase.

Since the License is perpetual you may keep using the current version of the product you have installed. The software will never stop working.

Comment: Please edit ALL your answers to ***FULLY DISCLOSE*** your affiliation with this product.  Otherwise, all your answers will be deleted as spam.  Your only contribution to this entire site is multiple answers promoting your own product, without ever disclosing this fact.

Comment: You're welcome.  Thank *you*.  An additional way to make your answers non-spam - and I think you've done a pretty good job of this - is to ensure each of your answers specifically answers the question being asked, and is not just an ad for your product.  Also don't put down other answers or products with comments like "you get what you pay for".  Thanks again for your help in keeping this site free of spam.

Comment: Thanks for the update from me, too, Andrew! Maybe a hint to the pricing model would be appropriate to include as well. One might not expect USD 700..28k, and seeing "renewals" in your price list makes it unclear for how long such a license is valid. Seeing the term "subscription" along, this suggests a monthly or yearly fee?